# Wordpress New Theme Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I made new Theme in Wordpress But i am getting 1 issue. When i add Images in Post Editor WP Backend. I align some images to Right. Then On Front End The Images becomes only on Left side and Center. Images are not aligning properly.

Please help me to make these well aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't include the CSS for WordPress generated elements:

https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes

WordPress aligns images using the `alignleft`, `alignright`, `aligncenter` etc. classes. If you don't include any styling for those classes then images that are aligned in the editor will not be aligned on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your theme file style.css and add the following lines:

```
.alignright {
    float:right;
    margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
}
```

Good luck1